# How do I spawn a child process as a different user on Windows?

Tags: node.js, child-process, libuv

Since libuv [does not support](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/v0.11.1/src/win/process.c#L768-771) `child_process.spawn`'s `uid` [option](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) on Windows, how can you spawn a child process that runs as a different user?

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot is to use "runas" command line tool for Windows. "runas /?" for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. It specifically says in the documentation that there is no option available for that on windows. http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setuid_id

But if all you want to do is start as admin, because you need to bind to a privileged port, then there are other smarter ways of doing that, which will let you use a privileged port with a normal user.

Comment: So, what are these smarted ways to run as Admin?